# applying a FOR loop to a function

Tags: python

good day! How to properly apply a FOR loop to a given function?

thanks for the tips:)

```
from datetime import timedelta

from apps.tickets.models import PatientConsultationTicket


 def tickets_change():
     tickets = PatientConsultationTicket.object.all()
     one_day = tickets.created_at + timedelta(days=1)
     if datetime.now() > one_day:
         tickets.status = 'rd'
         tickets.save()
     elif datetime.now() < one_day:
         tickets.status = 'e'
         tickets.save()
```

Comment: Do you want a for loop that calls the function? Or a for loop in the function? What is the purpose of the for loop, is it iterating over a set of inputs? Is it just running the function multiple times?

Comment: `for i in range(<num_of_iterations>): tickets_change() `

Comment: for the for loop to constantly perform actions

Comment: you need pass to the function the object on where you want do the loop and then use the for loop example posted in the comment by other users ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question that's how you can iterate on the tickets :

```
from datetime import timedelta

from apps.tickets.models import PatientConsultationTicket


def tickets_change():
    tickets = PatientConsultationTicket.objects.all()
    for ticket in tickets:
        one_day = ticket.created_at + timedelta(days=1)
        if datetime.now() > one_day:
            ticket.status = 'rd'
            ticket.save()
        elif datetime.now() < one_day:
            ticket.status = 'e'
            ticket.save()
```

Though, it's probably not the best way to do what you want.
Instead you should probably use an "UPDATE" query (not tested but it could look to something like that):

```
PatientConsultationTicket.objects.filter(created_at__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=1)).update(status='rd')
PatientConsultationTicket.objects.filter(created_at__lte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=1)).update(status='e')
```

Comment: @ElizabethBylatova I'm glad I did, if you like the answer please vote it up and accept it clicking on the v left to the answer, that rewards me for my modest efforts :)